# jQuery panel slider flickers

Tags: jquery, slider

I am working on a simple continuous slider panel. It seems to work find but the prev direction flickers when it slides. I tried moving the order of the jQuery actions around but it doesn't seem to help, any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/FWUSA/3

```
$(".next").click(function () {
    $('.slides').animate({
        'marginLeft': '-=530px'
    }, function () {
        $('ul.slides li:last').after($('ul.slides li:first'));
        $(".slides").css('marginLeft', 0);
    });
});

$(".prev").click(function () {
    $('.slides').animate({
        'marginLeft': '530px'
    }, function () {
        $('ul.slides li:first').before($('ul.slides li:last'));
        $(".slides").css('marginLeft', 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: What browser are you seeing the flickering in?

Comment: Am I supposed to be seeing all the images at once? Animations tend to flicker when a lot of stuff is moved because the video processor is overtaxed.

Comment: What i think it is doing is when it tries to move the last image to the beginning there's no room so it is getting put down below, then popping p into place, causing a flicker. I am on Chrome... you should see one image at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You applied a single class to all of the images and your code applies to the class.

```
$(".slides").css('marginLeft', 0);
```

This controls all elements with a class of slides. Since all of your images have that class, they'll all move at once. You need to find a way to differentiate each image. Try adding a `.next()`.
http://api.jquery.com/next/

************My opinion********************

I believe you're trying to create a JQuery slider?

I went down that route a few weeks ago. Though I had one the ended up functioning, it wasn't great. There are tons of browser work-arounds and hacks that are required. I'd advise using a plugin. I'm using Flexslider.  http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

It's able to be customized, simple, uses JQuery, lightweight.

Comment: The client I am working for requires everything to be proprietary. It just needs to simple functions: scroll left, scroll right. Why does it go smoothly one direction and not the other?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and I don't receive any flickering. I'm honestly not sure. According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956026/jquery-slider-panel-flickers?rq=1) it can be caused by not having it fixed width.